# Split array arguments of a function using "..." R

Tags: r, function, arguments

The following function creates a data.frame with n columns as the number of arguments

```
functionWithDots <- function(...) {
  f1 <- function(x) c(x,x+4)
  list <- list(...)
  list <- lapply(list, f1)
  expand.grid(list)
  }
```

When running it as
functionWithDots(1,2)
The expected result is:

- id Var1 Var2

  1. 1    2
  2. 5    2
  3. 1    6
  4. 5    6

while if I do the same by replacing "(1,2)" with "1:2" as

```
functionWithDots(1,2)
```

the result is

- id Var1

  1. 1
  2. 2
  3. 5
  4. 6

How can I pass the correct unconcatenated argument to that functions since it seems to return different results when passing, let's say, "1,2,3" instead of "c(1,2,3)"?

Comment: If you have your arguments in a "list"/"vector" you can, also, use `do.call`: `args = 1:2; do.call(functionWithDots, as.list(args))`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that I understood the problem correctly, ie. the OP wanted to get the same results by passing `1,2` and `1:2` in the `functionWithDots`, here is one way to fix it.  We convert the elements in `...` to `list` for both the cases and it should give the same result for both cases.

```
functionWithDots <- function(...) {
   f1 <- function(x) c(x,x+4)
   dots <- c(...)
   list <- as.list(dots)
   list <- lapply(list, f1)
   expand.grid(list)
 }


functionWithDots(1,2)
#  Var1 Var2
#1    1    2
#2    5    2
#3    1    6
#4    5    6
 functionWithDots(1:2)
#  Var1 Var2
#1    1    2
#2    5    2
#3    1    6
#4    5    6
```

Checking with `1:3` vs `1,2,3`

```
functionWithDots(1,2,3)
#  Var1 Var2 Var3
#1    1    2    3
#2    5    2    3
#3    1    6    3
#4    5    6    3
#5    1    2    7
#6    5    2    7
#7    1    6    7
#8    5    6    7

functionWithDots(1:3)
#  Var1 Var2 Var3
#1    1    2    3
#2    5    2    3
#3    1    6    3
#4    5    6    3
#5    1    2    7
#6    5    2    7
#7    1    6    7
#8    5    6    7
```

---

Now, let's see the problem in the OP's function (removed the `lapply` and `expand.grid`)

```
functionWithDots <- function(...) {
  f1 <- function(x) c(x,x+4)
  list <- list(...)
  print(list)
}
```

In the first case `1:2`, the function is returning a `list` of `length` 1

```
functionWithDots(1:2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2
```

while in the second, it returns a `list` with length equal to the number of elements in the input

```
functionWithDots(1,2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 2
```

In the modified function, both are returning `list` with length equal to the number of elements in the input argument.

```
functionWithDots <- function(...) {
  f1 <- function(x) c(x,x+4)
  dots <- c(...)
  list <- as.list(dots)
  print(list) 
 }

functionWithDots(1:2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 2

functionWithDots(1,2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 2
```